# Add a column from the same table without adding in Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a structure table that has more than 5000 structures along with over 20 columns. I will only show 3 structures and 4 columns for simplicity. I will call this Table S.

| Structure ID | Structure Name | Structure Status | Structure Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Fraser | Open | 120 |
| 7 | Roger Cr | Open | 176 |
| 8 | Toby | Open | 105 |

The other table is about the inspections of the structures shown above. This table is called Table I. Few of its columns will be shown.

| Structure ID | Inspection Date | Structure Index | Urgency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 27-May-2003 | 2.16 | 3 |
| 5 | 28-Apr-2004 | 1.65 | 5 |
| 5 | 16-Aug-1999 | 3.15 | 5 |
| 5 | 15-May-2013 | 2.54 | 2 |
| 5 | 12-Sep-1995 | 1.99 | 2 |
| 5 | 08-Dec-2012 | 2.13 | 3 |
| 7 | 06-Oct-2016 | 3.11 | 4 |
| 7 | 05-May-2022 | 1.77 | 2 |
| 7 | 14-Jun-2020 | 2.65 | 2 |
| 7 | 18-May-2013 | 1.89 | 1 |
| 7 | 21-Aug-2023 | 2.02 | 1 |
| 8 | 03-Jun-2010 | 1.76 | 3 |
| 8 | 28-Aug-2022 | 3.32 | 5 |
| 8 | 21-Oct-2021 | 1.98 | 1 |

What I want is that each structure only shows its latest inspection date. The code that I have used does get me the result.

Both the code and the result are shown below;

```
SELECT 
    a.structure_id "Structure ID",
    func.description "Function",
    a.NAME,
    b.description "Structure Status",
    a.structure_length "Structure Length",
    i.inspection_date "Inspection Date",
FROM 
    STRUCTURE a    
LEFT JOIN
    STRUCTURE_STATUS b ON a.STRUCTURE_STATUS = b.STRUCTURE_STATUS
LEFT JOIN 
    structure_elec_dist ed ON a.structure_id = ed.structure_id
LEFT JOIN 
    hwy_elec_dis hwy ON ed.elect_dis_no = hwy.elect_dist_no
LEFT JOIN 
    structure_function func ON a.structure_function = func.structure_functio
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT structure_id, MAX(inspection_date) AS "latest date"
     FROM structure_inspection
     GROUP BY structure_id) i ON a.structure_id = i.structure_id
```

The result is:

| Structure ID | Function | Name | Structure Status | Structure Length | Latest Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Bridge | Fraser | Open | 120 | 08-Dec-2012 |
| 7 | Bridge | Roger Cr | Open | 176 | 21-Aug-2023 |
| 8 | Bridge | Toby | Open | 105 | 28-Aug-2022 |

Unfortunately, its when I intend to include other columns from Table I such as 'Structure Index' and 'Urgency', that's when the rows begin to increase as I have to include them in `GROUP BY` clause as well which I do not want.

The result I want is:

| Struct ID | Func | Name | Struc Status | Structure Len. | Latest Date | Struc. Index | Urgency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Bridge | Fraser | Open | 120 | 08-Dec-2012 | 2.13 | 3 |
| 7 | Bridge | Roger Cr | Open | 176 | 21-Aug-2023 | 2.02 | 1 |
| 8 | Bridge | Toby | Open | 105 | 28-Aug-2022 | 3.32 | 5 |

I have been trying for the last two days to solve this. I looked at similar questions in Stackoverflow and somewhat tried incorporating the solutions given, but it didn't work out.

My apologies if I couldn't ask the question properly. Please do ask me to correct if there are any mistakes in it.

Your assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution based on the window function `ROW_NUMBER()`.

It is a two step process:

1. Our CTE ranks inspections for each structure via `PARTITION BY Structure_ID` clause based on their date order via `ORDER BY Inspection_Date DESC`.
2. `SELECT` after CTE applies `WHERE seq = 1` clause to filter out rows
   with seq value is greater than 1.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @structure TABLE (Structure_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Structure_Name VARCHAR(20), Structure_Status VARCHAR(20), Structure_Length INT);
INSERT @structure (Structure_ID, Structure_Name, Structure_Status, Structure_Length) VALUES
(5, 'Fraser',   'Open', 120),
(7, 'Roger Cr', 'Open', 176),
(8, 'Toby',     'Open', 105);

DECLARE @inspection TABLE (Structure_ID INT, Inspection_Date DATE, Structure_Index DECIMAL(4,2), Urgency INT);
INSERT @inspection (Structure_ID, Inspection_Date, Structure_Index, Urgency) VALUES
(5, '2003-05-27', 2.1, 3),
(5, '2004-04-28', 1.6, 5),
(5, '1999-08-16', 3.1, 5),
(5, '2013-05-15', 2.5, 2),
(5, '1995-09-12', 1.9, 2),
(5, '2012-12-08', 2.1, 3),
(7, '2016-10-06', 3.1, 4),
(7, '2022-05-05', 1.7, 2),
(7, '2020-06-14', 2.6, 2),
(7, '2013-05-18', 1.8, 1),
(7, '2023-08-21', 2.0, 1),
(8, '2010-06-03', 1.7, 3),
(8, '2022-08-28', 3.3, 5),
(8, '2021-10-21', 1.9, 1);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Structure_ID ORDER BY Inspection_Date DESC)
    FROM @inspection
)
SELECT s.*
    , rs.inspection_Date, rs.Structure_Index, rs.Urgency
FROM @structure AS s
    INNER JOIN rs ON rs.Structure_ID = s.Structure_ID
WHERE seq = 1;
```

**Output**

| Structure_ID | Structure_Name | Structure_Status | Structure_Length | inspection_Date | Structure_Index | Urgency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Fraser | Open | 120 | 2013-05-15 | 2.50 | 2 |
| 7 | Roger Cr | Open | 176 | 2023-08-21 | 2.00 | 1 |
| 8 | Toby | Open | 105 | 2022-08-28 | 3.30 | 5 |

Comment: Please don't add code-only answers, instead document why this is different to GROUP BY and how it works.